# no-same-owner flag in python tar extract

Tags: python, tar

I have a bash script that extracts a tar file:

```
tar --no-same-owner -xzf "$FILE" -C "$FOLDER"
```

`--no-same-owner` is needed because this script runs as root in Docker and I want the files to be owned by root, rather than the original uid/gid that created the tar

I have changed the script to a python script, and need to add the `--no-same-owner` flag functionality, but can't see an option in the docs to do so

```
with tarfile.open(file_path, "r:gz") as tar:
    tar.extractall(extraction_folder)
```

Is this possible? Or do I need to run the bash command as a subprocess?

Answer (score 0):

The `tar` command with the `--no-same-owner` option would extract and change the ownership to the user who executed the command. Please find below the quote from `man tar`.

> ```
>   --no-same-owner
>          extract files as yourself (default for ordinary users)
> ```

Hence it makes sense to provide this option only when you extract as a root user.

A similar option is available for Python 3.5 onwards.

> If numeric_owner is True, the uid and gid numbers from the tarfile are used to set the owner/group for the extracted files. Otherwise, the named values from the tarfile are used.

So it seems like the ownership of the tar file matters while extracting from Python.

Please go through the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractall) for more details.